# Duplicate rows in SQl query to estimate the db growth

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I am trying to estimate the database size and its compress backup. I am running below query to check the size and be able to get the rough idea of how much database would be growing in few weeks or so. However, when I run below query I am getting duplicate results for some reason and I can not figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),backup_start_date, 111) AS BackupDate,
 FLOOR( backup_size/1024000000) AS DBSize_GB,
 FLOOR(compressed_backup_size/1024000000) AS BackupSize_GB, Database_Name
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset as b
WHERE database_name = @dbname
 AND type = 'd'
 AND DATEPART(mm,backup_start_date) = @mon --comment this line for all the     months
ORDER BY 
backup_start_date DESC
```

Results:
[Attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xv6.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting duplicates? The `floor` might make it seem like non-duplicates are duplicated.

Comment: Actually, I am getting two results set for Compressed_backup_size which is same as backup_size for any given date.